# Entity Framework 4: Fetching data of two table and returning to persentation layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have two tables having 1 to 1 relationship. One table called `Person` and second is `PersonDetails`. `PesonId` is in `PersonDetails` table as `FK`.

I can query individual tables like

```
public static Person GetPersonById(int personId)
{
    using (var context = new REntities())
    {
    return context.Person.Where(p => p.PersonId == personId).First();
    }
}
```

It is being used in consuming code like:

```
Person personInfo = PersonService.GetPersonById(personId);
```

and same with `PersonDetail` on its PK i.e. `PersonDetailId`

But when I have to fetch data from two tables then I am not understanding that what how would I do this and what would be the best way to return data to presentation layer.

Following would be the code to get `Person` and relate `PersonDetails` records:

```
from personData in context.person.Include("PersonDetail")
                                  where personData.PersonId == personId
                                  select personData;
```

What is personData here?
How can I iterate over it and get each item in client code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get your Person object, you can include the PersonDetails object as well within the query like this...

```
using (var context = new REntities())
{
  return context.Person.Include("PersonDetail").Where(p => p.PersonId == personId).First();
}
```

Now on the presentation side, when you get the Person object, iterate through each item of person detail like this...

```
from p in personInfo.PersonDetails
select p; // here p is the person detail object
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework Code First (EF 4.1), mark the `PersonDetails` property in the `Person` class as `virtual`. This will enable EF to populate the data automatically so you can simply do `person.PersonDetails` to get your list of data